# Ajax .Post - Sending own defined variable through to mail.php

Tags: php, html, ajax, email, post

I am getting info from rest of the variables but the last one I want to send in my own which is predefined. But for some reason it aint going through to mail.php

```
var IT1 = "IT Service" ;
//send the ajax request
$.post('mail.php',{name:$('#name').val(),
companyname:$('#companyname').val(),
designation:$('#designation').val(),
ONumber:$('#ONumber').val(),
MNumber:$('#MNumber').val(),
email:$('#e-mail').val(),
message:$('#message').val(),
Manage:$('#Manage1').val(),
Tech:$('#Tech1').val(),
IT:$IT1},
```

mail.php looks like:

```
<?php
// declare our variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
$companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$ONumber = $_POST['ONumber'];
$MNumber = $_POST['MNumber'];
$IT = $_POST['IT'];
$Tech = $_POST['Tech'];
$Manage = $_POST['Manage'];

// set a title for the message
$subject = "Message from Your Website";
$body = "Name: $name\r\n, 
E-mail: $email\r\n, 
Company Name: $companyname\r\n, 
Designation: $designation\r\n, 
Office Number: $ONumber\r\n, 
Mobile: $MNumber\r\n,
Services: $IT, $Tech, $Manage\r\n,
Message: \n\n$message\r\n";
```

Comment: can you look at your browser dev tools and look at the post? how about looking at the $_REQUEST in PHP. make sure it's being sent. also one question, what's this: IT:$IT1 ???

Comment: Its suppose to be 
    IT:$('#IT').val()}

But thats not working so I was thinking if I was to pass that variable IT without the .val() function.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably follow the format of your other variables:

```
IT:$('#IT1').val() }
```

or

```
IT:$(IT1).val() }
```

Comment: I tried this before I posted here but these functions don't seem to work. I am not about to see the "IT Service" in the sent email!